# Orderby not ordering strings that include numbers in Linq

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, iqueryable

I have a string field in database that keeps numbers as string. when I want to order based on this field in Linq as below but orderby **does not** work well. it orders like this

1 - 2 - 3 - 25 - 11 - 30 - 50 ===> 1 - 11 - 2 - 25 - 3 - 30 - 50

```
   IQueryable<Tbl_Melk> Melks =
   from melk in Tbl_Melk
   where melk.Mantaghe == Mantaghe && melk.Hoze == Hoze && melk.Block == Block
   orderby melk.Melk
   select melk;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What says Maurice is right, You may try this:

```
var Melks = from melk in Tbl_Melk.ToList()
let integer = int.Parse(melk)
orderby integer
where melk.Mantaghe == Mantaghe && melk.Hoze == Hoze && melk.Block == Block
orderby melk.Melk
select melk;
```

But with that you are losing performance and the IQuerable interface.

Comment: tnx but it has **error**: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Ups, Linq is trying to convert it to a sql statement, I will add a workaround but it is less efficient.

Comment: Just in case the solution posted there [Linq - Order by number then letters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120970/linq-order-by-number-then-letters) also does the sorting in the program.

Comment: If you need make that sorting in the database engine you may consider change your design. The type of the column 'Melk' should be numeric (int).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, that is the correct order because it's sorting the values in alphabetic order.  LINQ cannot tell that the data contains numbers unless you coerce it into a numeric type.  Check out this question for one way to sort the way you want.

[Linq - Order by number then letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120970/linq-order-by-number-then-letters)

Answer (score 1):

LeftPad the string with zeros.

Out of my brain and to the lack of EntityFramework not supporting LeftPad:

```
....
orderby SqlFunctions.Replicate("0", 10 - melk.Melk.Length) + melk.Melk
```