# Linq to sort by letter then number?

Tags: c#, linq

Lets say I have the following:

```
1
B
2
C
4
A
```

How would I sort this to give me this?

```
A
B
C
1
2
4
```

My code sorts by number and then letters.

```
var result = list1.OrderBy(x => x.value).ToList();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linq - Order by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120970/linq-order-by-number-then-letters) there are great answers here, just pick one and reverse the predicate...

Answer (score -1):

If you just care about the first character, then you can use:

```
var result = list1.OrderBy(x => x.value >= "A" ? 0 : 1)
                  .ThenBy(x => x.value);
```

Comment: since you did not specified more details here it is 2 options:

Char[] s = new Char[] {'1','B','2','C','4','A'};
 s.OrderByDescending(o=> (Char.IsNumber(o)))
 .OrderBy(o=> o).Dump();
 
 string[] ss = new string[] {"1","B","2","C","4","A"};
 
 s.OrderByDescending(o=> (o is int))
 .ThenBy(o=> o);